# playerglobal.swc Internal Version

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-builder, flash

How I can determine the INTERNAL_VERSION of Flash to correctly create a **FlashPlayer13_0.xml**?

I mean: `<player id="FlashPlayer13.0" version="INTERNAL_VERSION" asversion="3">`

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't that be version **24**, as indicated by [these release notes](http://helpx.adobe.com/en/flash-player/release-note/fp_13_air_13_release_notes.html)?